# GD extension for PHP 5.6.20

Tags: php, php-5.6, php-gd

I have a vagrant box with LAMP. Linux distribution is Ubuntu 14.04.1
My PHP project has got a composer package and it's package use gd extension. I install php5-gd and added to php.ini file but it's not sold the problem. I type "php -v" to terminal it's return:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: gd: Unable to initialize module
>
> Module compiled with module API=20121212
>
> PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
>
> These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP 5.6.20-3+donate.sury.org~trusty+1

Does anyone help me? I think this problem maybe experienced from anyone before me.

Comment: The message basically tells it all already … the API versions the module and PHP were compiled against must match, obviously. So you need to go looking for the php5-gd package with the matching API version.

Comment: Why given negative point I didn't understand any shit.

Answer (score 0):

**Solve of this problem**

PHP 5.6.20+ version is not stable and packages maybe incompatible. You should be see in [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/version.cgi?collapse=1;info=1;package=php5-gd;found=php5%2F5.6.5%2Bdfsg-1;absolute=0) which version is stable. I want to find specific version of extensions and found in [here](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/amd64/php5.6-gd/download).

I get with wget debian package of php-gd extension:

```
wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php5.6/php5.6-gd_5.6.20+dfsg-3_amd64.deb
```

And install with dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg - i php5.6-gd_5.6.20+dfsg-3_amd64.deb
```

It's continue to return error message like this:

> dpkg: warning: downgrading php5.6-gd from 5.6.20+dfsg-3+donate.sury.org~trusty+1 to 5.6.20+dfsg-3
>
> (Reading database ... 73009 files and directories currently installed.)
>
> Preparing to unpack .../php5.6-gd_5.6.20+dfsg-3_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking php5.6-gd (5.6.20+dfsg-3) over (5.6.20+dfsg-3+donate.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
>
> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5.6-gd:
>
> php5.6-gd depends on php5.6-common (= 5.6.20+dfsg-3); however:
>
> Version of php5.6-common on system is 5.6.20+dfsg-3+donate.sury.org~trusty+1.
>
> php5.6-gd depends on libgd3 (>= 2.1.1); however:
>
> Version of libgd3:amd64 on system is 2.1.0-3.
>
> php5.6-gd depends on libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1); however:
>
> Package libjpeg62-turbo is not installed.
>
> php5.6-gd depends on libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1); however:
>
> Package libpng16-16 is not installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing package php5.6-gd (--install):
>
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>
> Processing triggers for php5.6-fpm (5.6.20+dfsg-3+donate.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
>   php5.6-fpm stop/waiting
>   php5.6-fpm start/running, process 11382
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    php5.6-gd

This informations say our "php5.6-common" package must be install at system. For fix this problem is this command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

After this command will upgrade "php5.6-gd" and installed correct package. I type terminal "php -v" and it's say me everything is good:

> PHP 5.6.20-3+donate.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
>
> Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>
> with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
>
> with Xdebug v2.4.1-dev, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans